# Show only results in query with more then 2 hits

Tags: mysql, sql

didnt find a solution yet... ;-)

suppose this is the result of a query:

```
ID, SUBS, DATE . 
19967,142, 2017-06-15 . 
20214,147, 2017-05-09 .
20214,137, 2017-06-07 . 
20303,147, 2017-05-31 .
```

and i want only the records with an ID who are more then 1 time in result, but i do want the 2 or more records, so not GROUP BY.

How to manipulate the query?

Comment: What query? You haven't shown anything aside from some unformatted results. (I formatted it, but still - not sure what you're asking)

Comment: i'm sorry not really familiar with the format here, hope this is beter... excuse me

Comment: Ideally, a querstion like this would include an SQL Fiddle or equivalent with sample data and queries.  As is, we can't show you a real query against the data without essentially making up the tables and queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`, assuming the dates are different:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.id and t2.date <> t.date
             );
```

Based on the context of the question, I interpret "more than 2" to actually be "2 or more".  Otherwise an aggregation would be necessary.

Comment: I wonder if that might be faster than enumerating the ones that are different.  Not sure if date comparison or count ( my answer ) would be more efficient.

Comment: You can try the two for comparison, but this should be faster with an index on `t(id, date)`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it in 2 steps - one to determine which IDs have multiples and another to select them.

There's many ways to do that; in this version, the ids having multiples are counted and then the data is selected separately.

In my (outdated) experience, large `IN` sets can be pretty slow.  If that list ends up being huge, it would make sense to use a temporary table to store the results so they can be indexed.  Regardless, an index on `id` seems like it could only help.

`select t.* from t where t.id in ( select id, count(*) c from t having c > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id) > 1);`

Answer (score -1):

create a table where it shows the number of occurrence of a record called sumRecords, and left join sumRecords with constraints as `WHERE occurrence > 1`

I am referring your table as `temp` Here is the code:

```
SELECT temp.* FROM 
temp LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ID, COUNT(*) occurance
FROM temp
GROUP BY ID) sumRecords ON temp.ID = sumRecords.ID
WHERE sumRecords.occurance > 1
```

result:

```
ID      subs     dat
20214   147     2017-05-09
20214   137     2017-06-07
```